Wrong output for Leetcode 4sum challenge
I am trying to solve LeetCode problem 18. 4Sum:

Given an array nums of n integers, return an array of all the unique quadruplets [nums[a], nums[b], nums[c], nums[d]] such that:

0 <= a, b, c, d < n
a, b, c, and d are distinct.
nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] + nums[d] == target

You may return the answer in any order.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,0,-1,0,-2,2], target = 0
Output: [[-2,-1,1,2],[-2,0,0,2],[-1,0,0,1]]
Constraints:

1 <= nums.length <= 200
-109 <= nums[i] <= 109
-109 <= target <= 109


This is my code:
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        int n = nums.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 3; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 2; j++) {
                if (j > i + 1 && nums[j] == nums[j - 1]) {
                    continue;
                }
                int low = j + 1;
                int high = n - 1;
                int tsum = target - (nums[i] + nums[j]);
                while (low < high) {
                    if (tsum == nums[low] + nums[high]) {
                        List<Integer> tans = Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j], nums[low],nums[high];
                        ans.add(tans);
                        while (low < high && nums[low] == nums[low + 1]) {
                            low++;
                        }
                        while (low < high && nums[high] == nums[high - 1]) {
                            high--;
                        }
                        low++;
                        high--;
                    } else if (tsum > nums[low] + nums[high]) {
                        low++;
                    } else {
                        high--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

My code gives a wrong output for case 291 (out of 297 cases):
Input:
nums = [1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000]
target = -294967296

Expected return value:
[]

My code returns:
[[1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000]]

I reviewed my code, but I didn't find any issue. I dry run the code and my answer seems right. But the LeetCode platform tells me the output is wrong.
What is my mistake?

The problem is the range of int. In the problematic test case you can see that the sum of 1000000000+1000000000+1000000000+1000000000 exceeds 231−1, and so it wraps around to -294967296, which happens to be the target. By consequence your program gives a false positive.
The solution is simple: use long when summing up int values. For just summing up two of nums values, there is no problem, because the code challenge says that these individual values are 109 at the most in absolute value, and twice that value is still in range of an int. But a sum with three such terms can lead to int-overflow. So:
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        int n = nums.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 3; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 2; j++) {
                if (j > i + 1 && nums[j] == nums[j - 1]) {
                    continue;
                }
                int low = j + 1;
                int high = n - 1;
                // Use long for calculating the sum:
                long tsum = (long) target - (nums[i] + nums[j]);
                while (low < high) {
                    if (tsum == nums[low] + nums[high]) {
                        List<Integer> tans = Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j], nums[low],nums[high]);
                        ans.add(tans);
                        while (low < high && nums[low] == nums[low + 1]) {
                            low++;
                        }
                        while (low < high && nums[high] == nums[high - 1]) {
                            high--;
                        }
                        low++;
                        high--;
                    } else if (tsum > nums[low] + nums[high]) {
                        low++;
                    } else {
                        high--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

